# Uniform convergence in every compact implying L2 convergence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence

I'm struggling with the following problem:

Suppose that $f$ and $f_n$ are analytic and bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, for every $n\in \mathbb N$, and their limit at infinity are zero, i.e.
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = 0.$$ 
In addition, for every compact $K \subset \mathbb R$ we have uniform convergence
$$\|f - f_n\|_{\infty,K} = \sup_{x\in K}|f(x)-f_n(x)| \rightarrow  0.$$

Is this enough to conclude that we have $L_2$ convergence on $\mathbb R$ ? (i.e. 
$$ \|f - f_n\|_{L_2}^2 = \int_{0}^{\infty} (f-f_n)^2 dx \rightarrow 0  ~~??)$$

Many thanks!

Comment: Let $\varphi$ be a bump function, and $f_n(x) = \varphi(x-n)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I could be mistaken (I'm not as experienced as you) but I don't think bump functions are analytic. I think the example you wanted to suggest was something like $f_{n}(x)=\frac{\sin(x-n)}{x-n}$.

Comment: @user71352 I forgot about the analyticity condition when I wrote the comment. But if we agree to call $x \mapsto \exp(-x^2)$ a bump function, that will do.

Comment: @DanielFischer It seems fair to regard it as such.

Comment: Thank you guys! Do you know if there is any hypothesis I could include to have uniform convergence in every compact implying $L_2$ convergence ?

Comment: It might be sufficient that the $f_n$ are the partial sums of a complex power series ; see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2881560